# Set multiple icon sizes using PyInstaller

Tags: python, icons, pyinstaller

I've created a exe from a Python file using `PyInstaller` and including an file icon. However it only shows when I have the folder option set to small icons (I'm using Windows 7).

Do I need to specify icons for when the folder option is set to display medium or large icons, and if so how?

The ico file I have at the moment is 128 x 128 px if that's important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build your ico file so that it embeds all sizes you wish to display.
Download a free icon that has all sizes to test with, like this one.

http://www.iconfinder.com/icondetails/17840/128/ark_arrow_box_download_dropbox_kde_package_icon

Then you can use the free program called icofx to edit your own ico file and generate the different sizes you need.

Good Luck! Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've been using a website to generate the ico file and when I open it up in icofx it shows all the sizes. I can't get it to repeat the behaviour any more so it's a mystery.